# Thevenin Equivalent of BJT Transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, linear

I wonder if I can replace a BJT transistor operating in active mode, with its Thevenin Equivalent, like this:

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

My guess is that I can, because the large signal model of the BJT operating in active mode is made of linear components:

[image]

Assuming that it's possible to apply the Thevenin Equivalent, how should I compute Rth? I know that I should set the independent sources to 0, but should I consider  VEB(on) = 0.7V as an independent source?

Answer (score 1):

Let me replicate your work at the top. (I can't say I understand why you wrote what you did after that, so I'll ignore it here.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMt2rs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's easy to convert from Norton to Thevenin in the last one in the bottom right corner: \$V_{TH}=205.8\:\mu\textrm{A}\cdot 20\:\textrm{k}\Omega=4.116\:\textrm{V}\$. So I follow you for the most part in the upper part of your statement. But that's where I think I stop following what you want to know.

Comment: I know Thévenin/Norton's Theorem apply only to linear devices, but I also know that a transistor is, in general, a non linear device. So, my concern was if it's possible/licit to apply Thévenin/Norton's Theorem to a transistor operating in active mode. My guess was that, as long as the transistor remains in active mode, it's possible to apply Thévenin/Norton's Theorem, because a transistor in active mode is modeled with linear elements. I just wanted to know if you guys could confirm if my guess was correct or not. Thank you.

Comment: @user246185 And again, I can't tell exactly what is in your head here. There is no way to replace the BJT with a resistor, for example, because the current in the emitter resistor has a different current than the collector resistor. Any added series resistor would require those currents to be the same. So it just doesn't work, if that is your goal. But I honestly can't say I know what you intended at the bottom, using what looked like a small signal model for a large signal question and maybe trying to replace a 3-term device with a 2-term device. But I'm probably just confused.

Answer (score 0):

Almost. But not even close.

- Zin (base) = ~ hFE*Re so Rb2 is reduced slightly.
- Zout (emitter) changes from a current source to a voltage source with Zout =~ Rb/Hfe for AC coupled load signals that draw less current than Ie, otherwise it rises to open circuit for negative AC currents approach the DC bias.
- Any further DC load attached to emitter reduces Rb even more but especially also Vbb2 quiescent V.